# print the php code

Tags: php

i want to simple like this

```
echo "$_POST['id']" . $_POST['id'];
```

so how can i print this string and its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '$_POST[\'id\']' . $_POST['id'];
```

Single quotes `'` print a literal string, variables within double quotes `"` are evaluated. Note that you have to escape single quotes within a single quoted string.

Alternatively escape the variable within double quotes to prevent it from being evaluated:

```
echo "\$_POST['id']" . $_POST['id'];
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

`echo '$_POST[\'id\']' . $_POST['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

`echo '$_POST["id"]' . $_POST['id']`

If you have a variable $x='abc' and you do

`echo '$x'` it prints `$x`

and if you do

`echo "$x"` it prints `abc`

Simply put, whatever variables you put into the double quotes get replaces by their values. If you use simple quotes the variables are not replaced.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these will basically do what you want:

```
echo "\$_POST['id']" . $_POST['id'];

echo '$_POST[\'id\']' . $_POST['id'];

echo '$_POST["id"]' . $_POST['id'];
```

When you use double-quotes, PHP will try to expand variable references inside of the string.  You can prevent variable expansions by using backslash to escape the dollar-sign part of the variable reference.

You can also use single-quotes to prevent variable expansions but if you need to actually print a single-quote then you need to use backslash to escape the single-quote.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but do you know about this?

```
print_r($_POST);
```

If you are just looking for some simple way to help you debug, this is very useful.  If you want it nice, you can put `<pre></pre>` around it.